# Can r600g drive 3D displays?

Tags: drivers, radeon, gpu, open-source

Can open-source Radeon (r600g) driver output stereoscopic image to displays that support it? Is it not mentioned in [Radeon feature matrix](http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature) (currently down, [archive link](http://web.archive.org/web/20130420205235/http://www.x.org/wiki/RadeonFeature)) and I couldn't find any info online.

If not, can at least fglrx/Catalyst do that? In 2012 it was supported [only on professional FirePro boards](http://devgurus.amd.com/thread/158704), not consumer-grade Radeon. Is Radeon supported now?

Answer (score 1):

I've seen support for HDMI Stereo 3D [land in Intel driver](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTQ3NzE) for Linux 3.13, but there was no word of stereo 3D in r600g whatsoever, so I have to assume that it doesn't support Stereo 3D. But I have no 3D displays to actually test if it works.

And I still have no info about support for HDMI 3D in Catalyst.

Comment: Have a look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/810404/send-stereoscopic-image-via-hdmi-frame-packing/. Check the fglrx driver for relevant calls to the drm module.